# Expression for 'Find' command

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use 'Find' command to search for a word one cell at a time instead of a range of cells at a time. I tried using 'For Each' command as shown below but it does not work. Is it possible to search for word using other expressions such as e.g `Set rgFound = activecell.Find("John")` or  `Set rgFound = cells(1,1).Find("John"))` apart from using 'range'?

```
Sub tester()
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rng = Columns(1)
    Set rng1 = rng.SpecialCells(xlVisible)

    For Each cell In rng1
        Set rgFound = cell.Find("John")
        If rgFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Name was not found."
        Else
            MsgBox "Name found in :" & rgFound.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search in the value of one single cell you must use the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

```
If InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, "John", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'John was found
Else
    'John was not found
End If
```

`InStr` returns the *first* position where `John` was found in the value of cell A1, so if it returns a number `> 0` then it was found otherwise not.

---

Alternatively you can use the [Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator):

```
If Range("A1").Value Like "*John*" Then
    'John was found
Else
    'John was not found
End If
```

Note the surounding placesholders (`*` asterisks) to ensure the like operator recognizes `John` in `"any string that conains John in the begining middele or end of the string"`

Comment: Feel free to accept helpful answers to your questions by ticking the green check mark and/or to upvote; would be helpful for guiding other users, too :-)